# Does batch_first affect hidden tensors in Pytorch LSTMs?

Tags: lstm, pytorch

Does `batch_first` affect hidden tensors in Pytorch LSTMs?

That is if `batch_first` parameter is true, 
Will the hidden state be `(numlayer*direction,num_batch,encoding_dim)`
or `(num_batch,numlayer*direction,encoding_dim)`

I've tested both, both give no error.

Answer (score 8):

I was thinking about the same question some time ago. Like laydog outlined, in the documentation it says

> batch_first – If True, then the input and output tensors are provided
>   as (batch, seq, feature)

As I understand the question we are talking about the hidden / cell state tuple, not the actual inputs and outputs.

For me it seems pretty obvious that this does not affect the hidden state as they mention:

> (batch, seq, feature)

This clearly refers to inputs and outputs, not the state tuple which consists of two tuples with shape:

> (num_layers * num_directions, batch, hidden_size)

So I'm pretty certain the hidden and cell states are not affected by this, it also would not make sense to me changing the order hidden state tuple.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?#torch.nn.LSTM)

> batch_first – If True, then the input and output tensors are provided as (batch, seq, feature)

So, yeah, if your input is batch first then the output will also be batch first.

Comment: Here the question is that if it is the same for hidden state or not.
Thank you anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at an example

```py
batch_size = 8
sequence_length = 10
input_dim = 64
lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=input_dim, hidden_size=32, num_layers=1, batch_first=True, bidirectional=False)
lstm_input = torch.randn(batch_size, sequence_length, input_dim)
output, (hidden, cell) = lstm(lstm_input)
# >>> output.shape, hidden.shape, cell.shape
# (torch.Size([8, 10, 32]), torch.Size([1, 8, 32]), torch.Size([1, 8, 32]))
```

So we can see that the `output` variable is batch first, but the hidden and cell state isn't.

Things become a bit more complex when you want to feed in the initial hidden or cell state

You might *expect* this to work:

```py
initial_cell = torch.randn(batch_size, 1, 32)
initial_hidden = torch.randn(batch_size, 1, 32)
# WARNING, THIS DOES NOT WORK, IT IS AN EXAMPLE!
# >>> output, (hidden, cell) = lstm(lstm_input, (initial_hidden, initial_cell))
# RuntimeError: Expected hidden[0] size (1, 8, 32), got [8, 1, 32]
```

Which means that the input hidden and cell state must be in `(sequence length, batch, hidden dim)` format.

```py
initial_cell = torch.randn(1, batch_size, 32)
initial_hidden = torch.randn(1, batch_size, 32)
output, (hidden, cell) = lstm(lstm_input, (initial_hidden, initial_cell))
# >>> output.shape, hidden.shape, cell.shape
# (torch.Size([8, 10, 32]), torch.Size([1, 8, 32]), torch.Size([1, 8, 32]))
```

Consequently we can see that regardless of `batch_first`, the hidden and cell state is always in the format `(seq, batch, dim)` whether it is an input or output argument to the `LSTM` cell.

The same holds for the hidden state of a GRU.